# Inserting a date and time

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I'm trying to insert the values from a date picker and a time pickers in my sqlite database. I have stored the date and time in object variables and then call a method in my DBhandler class to insert them through a contentvalue object.

Now where I'm failing here is with the actual insertion and data types.

I'm getting an error on the following code for the 'timeApp' and 'dateApp' I'm passing these variables to the createAppointmentEntry' method as DATE and TIME variables.:

Error message:

```
 The method put(String, String) in the type ContentValues is not applicable for the arguments (String, Time)
```

Method the errors occuring on:

```
public void createAppointmentEntry(String nameApp, String typeApp, Time timeApp, Date dateApp ,String commentApp, Boolean onOrOff) {



        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        cv.put(KEY_NAMEAPP, nameApp);
        cv.put(KEY_TYPEAPP, typeApp);

                    //ERROR on the following two 'puts'
        cv.put(KEY_TIMEAPP, timeApp);
        cv.put(KEY_DATEAPP, dateApp);

        cv.put(KEY_COMMENTAPP, commentApp);
        cv.put(KEY_ALARM, onOrOff);
        ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);
```

Heres my DB columns:

```
    public static final String KEY_ROWAPPID = "_appid";
public static final String KEY_NAMEAPP = "app_name";
public static final String KEY_TYPEAPP = "app_type";
public static final String KEY_TIMEAPP = "app_time";
public static final String KEY_DATEAPP = "app_date";
public static final String KEY_COMMENTAPP = "app_comments";
public static final String KEY_ALARM = "app_alarm";
```

My onCreate method:

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEAPP + " (" +
            KEY_ROWAPPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAMEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TYPEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TIMEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_DATEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_COMMENTAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_ALARM + "BOOLEAN NOT NULL);"

                );
```

Heres how I am setting the time and date object variables:

```
    Date setDate = new Date(dobYear - 1900, dobMonth, dobDate);


Time timeToSet = new Time();
timeToSet.set(0, dobMinute, dobHour);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the compilation error and the API of `ContentValues`, it seems that `ContentValues` only supports primitive types, `String` and `byte[]`. So, try replacing:

```
//ERROR on the following two 'puts'
 cv.put(KEY_TIMEAPP, timeApp);
 cv.put(KEY_DATEAPP, dateApp);
```

with:

```
 cv.put(KEY_TIMEAPP, timeApp.toString());
 cv.put(KEY_DATEAPP, dateApp.toString());
```

You can use formatter to format the `Time` and `Date` to a standard `String` to be able to parse it back.

Answer (score 0):

i guess something but i am not sure
`KEY_ALARM + "BOOLEAN NOT NULL);"`
you missed a whitespace at the create Statement. Try droping it and recreate it same just with the whitespace.

```
db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLEAPP + " (" +
            KEY_ROWAPPID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_NAMEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TYPEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TIMEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_DATEAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_COMMENTAPP + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_ALARM + " BOOLEAN NOT NULL);"
```

`KEY_ALARM + " BOOLEAN NOT NULL);"` 
Made the same misstage yesterday.
if you wrote a Helperclass just change the `DATABASE_VERSION` Else call the `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLEAPP);`
the Helper class would call this for example

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(MySQLiteHelper.class.getName(),
            "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLEAPP);
    onCreate(db); //recreate 
}
```

Automaticaly recreate the database with the new statement than.

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I have got as far as physcially inserting the data due to the fact Im not sure what is the correct data type to use on the date and time fields.

Comment: try using Date maybe? `DATE - format YYYY-MM-DD`
not sure if that may help. Take a look at http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html